# Short Text Topic Modelling in Python

Tags: python, nlp, topic-model, lda

I have a large dataset of short reviews and I would like to find the most recurring themes. For this reason, I got into topic modeling.

I am looking for some good tutorials and references for short text topic modeling.
I have seen that there exists a lot of material for LDA but when it comes to short texts there is not much, especially for python implementations.
I have found this [StackOverflow issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62175452/topic-modeling-on-short-texts-python) but is more than 2 year and a half old.

So, I would like to know if something more recent exists.
I know that there is a transformer-based model called [BertTopic](https://maartengr.github.io/BERTopic/index.html) that should perform reasonably well even on short text. Let me know if there is something that I am missing.

Thank you!